# Is there a way to make installing the AWS Tools in my Azure DevOps pipeline faster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, aws-cli, azure-powershell

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that runs a yaml file in my repo. Part of the process is running some Powershell scripts with the AWS DevOps Toolkit, but it takes a really long time for the AWS CLI to install on the agent every time. I'm wondering if there's a way to parallelize the process or something to start installing the module while the other agent is building?

I'd really like to close the feedback loop on testing this thing out if possible. Everything else in my pipeline takes under a minute, while this can sometimes take up to 6 or 7

Comment: If you can self-host your agents (e.g. on a VM you control), you could have the AWS CLI pre-installed, and not have to do the install in each pipeline run.
Is that an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not in this case. That absolutely would work though!

Comment: Does Azure DevOps allow caching directories? If yes, then cache whatever directory you install the CLI in.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow well enough to look into this more. does the agent live in a directory somewhere?